# MVC 3 generation URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

In my application i want to be able to send an email to a user. In Email i want to have an URL- link to an application page, but url have to be generic (because i need to be able to get some data from DB, depend on generic part of email).

For example :

I send email to user with URL : www.testpage.com/recetpassword/Qb12T

On load of the page i need to get data from DB and for example say Welcome UserName(which i get from DB).

Bad example, but it explains what i need

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5025059/1178921

Comment: sorry, but how can we specifically try to help you?

Comment: Great. What have you tried?  What are you having problems with? Show us your code and the problem you're having with it?  Right now your post just shows something you want to do; not what you're actually having problems with.

Comment: Have you tried the URL Helper for Url.Action or Url.RouteUrl? It is important that you use the last overload for all of these methods that allows you to specify the "protocol" and it will generate a full URL for you. Ex: Url.RouteUrl("ResetPassword",new { id = "Qb12T"},"http") or Url.Action("ResetPassword","Account",new { id = "Qb12T"},"http")

Comment: Thats the point, i dont know where to begin... something like that : ? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: @Timsen if you want a unique URL generated for each user for their password reset, we already have a question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025059/creating-unique-urls-in-asp-net If that's *not* what you want, then you're going to need to be a lot more specific in the business problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a new static route in your `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "reset_password", // Route name
                "resetpassword/{id}", 
                new { controller = "SomeController",
                      action = "ChangePassword",
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

Then in your Controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(string id){

        /* change password logic/domain calls */

        return View(/* some model */);
    }

}
```

Comment: After you've added the route and got that portion working you can use Url.RouteUrl("reset_password",new { id = "Qb12T"},"http") or Url.Action("ChangePassword","SomeController ",new { id = "Qb12T"},"http") to generate your links to place in your outgoing email.

Comment: how would local test Url look like to call that route?

Comment: http://localhost:1111/resetpassword/654sa65d4fas54df6a4sd